# 14.10 ver - Very Slow WiFi connection (Realtek)

Tags: wireless

I downloaded and installed Ubuntu on my laptop via bootable USB drive. 
The OS runs nice and smooth but the internet via WiFi is very slow: it takes ages to load a page, and sometimes it doesn’t even load.
The WiFi signal is good, but the speed is bad.

Is there a way to fix this?

Note: I never used Ubuntu before so please have patience with me.

Info:

output of `lspci -nnk`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller [8086:0044] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1033]
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1033]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller [8086:3b64] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1033]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller [8086:3b3c] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1033]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio [8086:3b56] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1033]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:3b42] (rev 05)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:3b44] (rev 05)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:3b48] (rev 05)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 [8086:3b4c] (rev 05)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller [8086:3b34] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1033]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller [8086:3b09] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1033]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:3b29] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1033]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller [8086:3b30] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1033]
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem [8086:3b32] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1033]
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3090]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:6891]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1033]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
3f:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers [8086:2c62] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1033]
3f:00.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder [8086:2d01] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1033]
3f:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 [8086:2d10] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1033]
3f:02.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 [8086:2d11] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1033]
3f:02.2 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core Processor Reserved [8086:2d12] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1033]
3f:02.3 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core Processor Reserved [8086:2d13] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1033]
arthur@arthur-CR620:~$
```

**Changed the encryption and it works fine now.**

Comment: Can you add some info from commands in terminal(CTRL + ALT + t) to your question `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: Not a duplicate - here we have Realtek, there it was Intel.

Comment: For the benefit of the searchers, please tell us what encryption made your Realtek work as expected. Thanks.